# Why didn't Antrax show any interest in the power source of the skyships?

Tags: shannara

Antrax showed an ability to use its imagination to somehow harness the power of magic to keep itself running and its batteries full.

It would seem that a much smaller imaginative leap would have been to tie in to the energy that powers the skyships, removing any need to lure potentially dangerous magic wielders to its secret location and allowing them through its heavily fortified defenses.

Is there any mention of the ships being somehow unsuitable?

Comment: I don't have enough of a memory into the book to answer in full, but I seem to recall Antrax operating on two core priorities - a, get as much as you can, and b, make sure you can get more.  Unless a fleet was brought, and there were crystals to spare, I don't think it would try that.

Answer (score 3):

Ships were actually powered by solar energy, absorbed using sails and directed through radian draws to crystals. The crystals were used to accumulate it for use at night or bad weather. Thus it was pointless for Anthrax to desire a second-hand energy source, while it could use solar energy directly (apparently, it was not enough for it to function properly).

From *Ilse Witch,* Chapter 4:

> Furl Hawken relayed the instructions to the men stationed at the front and rear parse tubes, where the **crystals were fed light** from the radian draws. Unhooding freed the mechanisms that allowed Alt Mer to fly the ship. Canvas coverings and linchpins securing the metal hoods that shielded the crystals were released, giving control over the vessel to the pilot box.

Comment: Once again, are there any sources you can find for your answer to provide evidence for you thoughts to strengthen your answer?

Comment: I will add evidence as soon as I have a book ready. In the first book of 'Voyage of Jerle Shannara' trilogy, the mechanics of a flying ship are explained. I just do not have it with me right now.

Comment: No problem! It'll just make your answer that little bit stronger (and less opinion based)

Comment: A possible issue with this is that the amount of energy gathered by each ship is enough to levitate the massive airship, in addition to all cargo and combat maneuvers (and weapons?). The ratio of surface area to the amount of energy required to do all this blows way past a theoretical 100% efficient solar cell.

Comment: @Michael Richardson, This is no science fiction, so conformance with physics law is not an issue ;-) Most magical weapons draw  the amount of energy equal to a small nuclear plant from sun, moon, stars, earth, etc. Typically it is assumed that other laws than physics are responsible for this, as it is a different world from ours.

Comment: @TimSparrow - absolutely, but the question isn't about if the crystals are plausible (this is fantasy as you say), it is if the crystals are that useful at converting energy, why weren't they fetched and used by the homicidial AI that was killing everything it could for energy?

Comment: @Radhil, as I have stated in the answer, the crystals are capable of storing solar energy. I guess that even if Anthrax steals all crystals from a single ship, it won't give it enough energy to operate for a significant time (years or decades) to bother stealing it.